# How to pass data in web services?

Tags: c#, web-services

I want to pass data user Id and user code to another server and get the response using network.

So, I created this code

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"http://10.2.1.85/");
```

It is working fine but I don't know how to pass the user Id and user code.

 Do I have to create object or something?

How can I do it?

Comment: You create a web project with methods decorated with the `[WebMethod]` attribute. Deploy the web app to a server (or local). Then in Visual Studio you reference the WebService and call its methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to Post Data on Web Service:

WebService Post Function

```
public static string JsonPost(string url, string method, string postData)
{

    Uri address = new Uri(url + method);

    //Get User current network credential
    ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    NetworkCredential credential = credentials.GetCredential(address, "Basic");

    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";

    //Network Credential should be included on the request to avoid network issues when requesting to the web service
    request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(credential.UserName, credential.Password, credential.Domain);
    request.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(credential.UserName, credential.Password, credential.Domain);

    byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
    using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
    }

    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        string JsonResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

        return JsonResponse;
    }
}
```

Login Function

```
public static string Login(string Email, string Password)
{

    try
    {
        string postData = "{" + "\"Email\":\"" + Email + "\"," +
        "\"Password\":\"" + Password + "\"" +
        "}";

        string JsonResult = JsonPost("Your Web Service URL", "Login", postData);
        return JsonResult;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return "";
    }

}
```

Example How To Use:

```
public void LoginUser()
{
    string Email = "me@example.com";
    string Password = "password";
    string JsonUserAccount = Login(Email, Password);

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(JsonUserAccount))
    {
        Debug.Print("User logged in");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Print("Failed to logged in");
    }

}
```

Comment: No use in overruling and hard coding email and password, right?

Comment: sorry, for the parameter I added on LoginUser(). now I removed the parameter so that the example would have static value or hard coding value for email and password. Anyway he could always add some Email and Password parameters on the method.